# magento-Assign Custom attribute value (from drop down) programatically

Tags: magento

I have to assign custom attributes from drop down menu. means we have lots of books and i create custom attribute for languages like English,Hindi,Punjabi etc. i have tried this

```
$product_id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(23340);
    echo "Product Name".$product_id->getName();
  $product_id->setStoreId(1)->setData(('book_lang'),24)->save();
```

where 24 is the id of my custom drop down attribute (for English) it works but it not shown in filter attributes.

any response is precious...

Answer (score 0):

hi for custom option check magento admin section and

in catalog.xml see this

```
<block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container1" as="container1">
                <action method="setDataByKey">
                    <key>alias_in_layout</key>
                    <value>container1</value>
                </action>
                <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry">
                    <key>options_container</key>
                    <key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry>
                </action>
                <action method="append">
                    <block>product.info.options.wrapper</block>
                </action>
                <action method="append">
                    <block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block>
                </action>
            </block>
            <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container2" as="container2">
                <action method="setDataByKey">
                    <key>alias_in_layout</key>
                    <value>container2</value>
                </action>
                <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry">
                    <key>options_container</key>
                    <key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry>
                </action>
                <action method="append">
                    <block>product.info.options.wrapper</block>
                </action>
                <!--                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>-->
            </block>
```

and check the product view.phtml for `$this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true)` please provide me some more information may be i will suggest you proper

and for filter try this `$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('costume_attribute_name', $productId);`

Comment: hi jeeten, thanxs for ur response.    my problem is that, i created a custom attribute language, and it have four value in this drop down, like English,Hindi,Bengali,Punjabi , and also i installed a plugin which filter products based on these attributes, my problem is that i set the drop down attributes and it works on frontend but the assign attribute not shown in backend and that's why the products are not visible in filter results...

Comment: @fivee hi may i know r you creating a new attribute set for product ya using product custom option

Comment: i am creating new attribute not attribute set, named book_lang and it have four values in option English,Hindi,bengali,punjabi i set these attributes programatically but the value of book_language attribute not set in the backend..

Comment: means its not set in admin panel when i see the product in backend the book_lang attribute shown blank value from the drop down('English,hindi,bengali,punjabi') although i set the book_lang value from the drop down ids like 23 for hindi, 21 for english etc and the set attribute shown in frontend correctl..

Comment: @fivee please create a new attribute from admin and assign it to default attribute set of the product, it will work and if you are using custom code to change value of ' book_lang '                            require_once '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app(); // this is for frontend and Mage::app('admin'); // this is for back end try this one